# If $M_n$ is a Martingale, How to Show that $\log M_n$ is a Supermartingale?

Tags: probability, martingales

I think that the problem should use Jensen's inequality.

This is because my textbook states that with Jensen's inequality, if $\phi$ is a convex function and $M_n$ a martingale, then $\phi(M_n)$ is a submartingale.

The problem is that $\log$ is not a convex function and I am trying to show the opposite direction.

Comment: $-\log x$ is convex, and the negative of a submartingale is a supermartingale.

Answer (score 5):

You have that $-\log x$ is a convex function. Then

$\mathbb{E}[-\log M_{n+1} | \mathcal{F_n}] \geq -\log(\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_n) = -\log(M_n)$

(I used Jensen in the first inequality)

Then, $-\log(M_n)$ is a submartingale and then $\log(M_n)$ is a supermartingale!

Answer (score 1):

A supermartingale can be thought of as a gambling game which is "super" for the casino, but not for those playing; i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n]\le X_n.$$

Note that for concave functions (like the logarithm), [Jensen's inequality reverses](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JensensInequality.html),  hence we have:

$$\mathbb{E}[\log M_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n] 
\le \log(\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n])  $$

Since $M_n$ is a martingale, $\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n]=M_n$, thus:

$$\mathbb{E}[\log M_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n] 
\le \log(\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n]) = \log M_n$$

$$\implies \mathbb{E}[\log M_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n] \le \log M_n$$

This is exactly what we needed to show, as one sees when comparing with the definition of supermartingale given above.

Comment: Note that the conditional expectation version of Jensen's inequality follows readily from the normal version http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275b.1.14w/PDFs/conditional-expectation.pdf -- so does the reversed version for concave functions also quickly generalize to the conditional case.